# Health insurance for family visiting from overseas

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, travel

I have an aunt and uncle planning on visiting the US from China for a stay of 5 months (on a tourist visa with Chinese passport) and I'm wondering what insurance to get them.  They're about 60 years old and in good health except for one exception -- my uncle got liver cancer about 1.5 years ago and had it treated surgically.  Apparently they were able to remove all the cancer, and nothing has show up in his few regular checkup CT scans since then.  They have health insurance back in China, but no travel insurance as of yet.

First of all, is there any insurance I can buy that would cover potential cancer treatment here if anything returns?  (I'm guessing the answer is no)

Second, what sort of insurance should I be looking for (travel, something else?) to cover typical ailments and doctors visits while they're here?

Thanks!

Comment: This might be better asked on travel.SE.

Comment: It's a very difficult issue, my guess is "you are out of luck".

Comment: It's called "visitors medical insurance" and you can indeed get coverage for "acute onset of pre-existing conditions" but, in general, not treatment for "pre-existing conditions". You need to contact a licensed insurance broker with your requirements and their health conditions to find an appropriate plan because the details of this vary by plan and are complicated.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that you would be looking at travel insurance. There are specific insurance plans that cover people coming to the United States from abroad that are just visiting. And, some plans, offer pre-existing coverage if the insured is under 70 years old.